# implementing an MQTT server capable of serving a website too

Tags: http, mqtt, esp32

*short question :* How can I host an MQTT server on my remote Ubuntu 16 server while at the same time hosting an HTTP server that will be using the MQTT data ?

*true question :* I want to build an IoT system that will be MONITORED and CONTROLLED by ESP32, which will SEND FEEDBACK and ACCEPT COMMANDS respectively from a remote server (maybe LAMP ?). I also want the user to log-in in a website hosted on this remote server, where s/he can monitor any sensor values or send commands (e.g. turning a led on or off).
So what's the way to go here?

I was adviced to go with MQTT but then the above problem arised.

*what I've found* : I 've found that using Mosquitto MQTT, I may be able to serve a website using websockets. But I prefer a more scalable HTTPS approach. That is, I intend to have a database linked with my site and running my PHP scripts.

I'm not that experienced, so please don't take anything for granted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MQTT uses TCP connection and follows publish/subscribe API model where as the web(http) follows Restful API model(Create,read,update,delete). If you want to stick with MQTT then you should use SAAS service like enterprise MQTT from [HIVE](https://www.hivemq.com/) which provide this integrability but will charge some fees and in return, they will provide you with an account and a dashboard for all your devices. Otherwise, you can try to make your own middleware which can integrate MQTT with web services .

Another thing I would recommend is [CoAP](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiWi4LNrv3aAhVFv48KHa1OC1kQFgg9MAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcoap.technology%2F&usg=AOvVaw2kCYddB4fHFFf2tvxS5gZB) which is also an M2M protocol but follows Restful API model and UDP connection. It has direct forward proxy to convert coap packets to https packets and vice versa.

In MQTT you have a central server(Broker) to which the nodes send their data and fetch their required data through `topic filters`.

In CoAP each device having some data to share becomes a server and the other device interested in it's data becomes  a client and sends a `GET` request to the respective server to get its data. Similarly a `PUT` request along with a payload from a client would update the value at the server.

Answer (score 0):

You really should not be looking to combine the MQTT broker with a HTTP server, especially if you intent the HTTP Server to actually be an application server (Running back end logic e.g. PHP). These are 2 totally separate systems. There is nothing to stop your application logic connecting to the broker as a client.

If you intend to use MQTT over WebSockets you can use something link nginx to proxy the WebSockets connection to the broker so it can sit behind the same logical HTTP/HTTPS address.